# Like operator doesn't work in Linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following LINQ query to filter files:

```
Dim arrayFiles As FileInfo()
Dim strFolder As String = "C:\Temp"
Dim strSearch As String = "[AFile].*"

Dim directoryInfo As DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path:=strFolder)
arrayFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern:=strSearch, 
                                    searchOption:=SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
                 Where(Function(s) s.Name.ToUpper Like strSearch.ToUpper).
                 ToArray()
```

In this example the specified folder contains 1 files: "[AFile].PDF". The above example returns 0 files (array is empty).

If I change the search pattern to "AFile.PDF" or "*.*" then I do get the correct array with 1 file.

Why does the search pattern "AFile.*" doesn't work in this example?

Comment: Contains doesn't work, afaik. The search pattern contains a wildcard.

Comment: On second thought, I think you don't need `where` at all. Just remove that

Comment: The wildcard is present only for the file extension or this is just as an example and you want also `AFile*.*` ?

Comment: I'm very sorry, my example wasn't right. The problem occurs only when the filename contains [] characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a search pattern to [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so there is no need to use additional `Where`:

```
arrayFiles = (New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path:=strFolder)).GetFiles(searchPattern:=strSearch,
                                   searchOption:=SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToArray
```

Your code is not working because `[]` brackets have a special meaning in VB.NET [LIKE operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx):

> [ *charlist* ] - Any single character in *charlist*

Hence you need to escape this special characters by enclosing them in brackets:

```
Dim strSearch As String = "[[]AFile[]].*"
```

*Note:* In fact you can escape only `[` because `]` has special meaning only when it is paired with `[`.

Comment: I'm using LINQ/Where because of the limitation where *.PDF will also include files with extensions like "PDF123".

Comment: @Marcus, ok, hence you can use `Where` but escape special characters.